# Não consigo manter tamanho fixo nas células de uma tabela

Tags: html, css

Boas, estou a fazer uma tabela e a preenchê-la com valores recebidos de uma base de dados.
O problema é que o tamanho das células adaptam-se ao valor do seu conteudo em vez de manterem o valor que defini para eles.
Alguem tem alguma solução?

O código da tabela é o seguinte :

```
table {
        max-width: 400px;
    }

    td,tr{
        width: 33px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Tipo</th>
            <th>Provisoes</th>
            <th>Pagamentos</th>
            <th>Acrescimos</th>
            <th>Liquidacoes</th>
            <th>Saldo</th>
            <th>Ac_Provisoes</th>
            <th>Ac_Pagamento</th>
            <th>Ac_Acrescimos</th>
            <th>Ac_Liquidacoes</th>
            <th>Ac_Saldo</th>

        </tr>

        <?php while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($query)) {
         ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $row['Tipo'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['Provisoes'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['Pagamentos'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['Acrescimos'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['Liquidacoes'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['Saldo'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['Ac_Provisoes'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['Ac_Pagamento'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['Ac_Acrescimos'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['Ac_Liquidacoes'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['Ac_Saldo'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de resolver isso é com a propriedade `table-layout`, usado o valor como `fixed` vc determina que o algorítimo de construção da tabela deve manter uma largura proporcional de todas as colunas, como vc pode consultar na documentação da Mozilla sobre o assunto: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

**OBS:** Essa é uma propriedade antiga, ainda do CSS2, então é amplamente aceita por todos os Browsers.

Agora seguem três modelos de tabela, um com `table-layout: fixed` e outra sem (`table-layout: auto`) para vc poder comparar, além de uma `fixed` com largura definida. *Exiba também em "Página toda" para ver como ela se comporta quando a tela aumenta*:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<p>table com table-layout: fixed</p>
<table >
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>texto</th>
     <th>texto texto texto</th>
     <th>texto texto</th>
     <th>te</th>
     <th>umapalavramuitomuitogrande</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>a</td>
     <td>b</td>
     <td>c</td>
     <td>d</td>
     <td>e</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>a</td>
     <td>b</td>
     <td>c</td>
     <td>d</td>
     <td>e</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>a</td>
     <td>b</td>
     <td>c</td>
     <td>d</td>
     <td>e</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<p>table com table-layout: fixed e largura fixa</p>

<table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 400px;">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>texto</th>
     <th>texto texto texto</th>
     <th>texto texto</th>
     <th>te</th>
     <th>umapalavramuitomuitogrande</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>a</td>
     <td>b</td>
     <td>c</td>
     <td>d</td>
     <td>e</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>a</td>
     <td>b</td>
     <td>c</td>
     <td>d</td>
     <td>e</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>a</td>
     <td>b</td>
     <td>c</td>
     <td>d</td>
     <td>e</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<p><i style="color:red">table com table-layout: auto</i></p>

<table style="table-layout: auto;">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>texto</th>
     <th>texto texto texto</th>
     <th>texto texto</th>
     <th>te</th>
     <th>umapalavramuitomuitogrande</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>a</td>
     <td>b</td>
     <td>c</td>
     <td>d</td>
     <td>e</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>a</td>
     <td>b</td>
     <td>c</td>
     <td>d</td>
     <td>e</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>a</td>
     <td>b</td>
     <td>c</td>
     <td>d</td>
     <td>e</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```